# React native firebase 6 Failed to install CocoaPods dependencies

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

im trying to use react native firebase version 6 with react native version 0.61 and i get Failed to install CocoaPods dependencie error when i try to create a new project using this [tutorial](https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/quick-start/new-project) , and when i use `pod instll --repo-update` or `pod install` it doesn't install some files like RNFirebase and Firebase core and etc , this is the error i get when i make a new project :

```
    apple@Apples-MacBook-Pro ~ % npx @react-native-community/cli init --template=@react-native-firebase/template Fbsix

               ######                ######               
             ###     ####        ####     ###             
            ##          ###    ###          ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##           ##    ##           ##            
            ##         ###      ###         ##            
             ##  ########################  ##             
          ######    ###            ###    ######          
      ###     ##    ##              ##    ##     ###      
   ###         ## ###      ####      ### ##         ###   
  ##           ####      ########      ####           ##  
 ##             ###     ##########     ###             ## 
  ##           ####      ########      ####           ##  
   ###         ## ###      ####      ### ##         ###   
      ###     ##    ##              ##    ##     ###      
          ######    ###            ###    ######          
             ##  ########################  ##             
            ##         ###      ###         ##            
            ##           ##    ##           ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##          ###    ###          ##            
             ###     ####        ####     ###             
               ######                ######               


                  Welcome to React Native!                
                 Learn once, write anywhere               

✔ Downloading template
✔ Copying template
✔ Processing template
⠙ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:796
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/apple/Fbsix/ios/undefined'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:793:17)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:686:27)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
error Error: Failed to install CocoaPods dependencies for iOS project, which is required by this template.
Please try again manually: "cd ./Fbsix/ios && pod install".
CocoaPods documentation: https://cocoapods.org/
```

all helps are appreciated, thank you

Comment: Hi @imcouri, have you found a solution?

Comment: no, i even asked it in Github, but React native firebase is ignoring this issue, so i had to switch to flutter and now I'm writing my app with flutter

Comment: Ho do you find it compare to RN?
P.S. My issue was outdated version of "@react-native-community/cli"

Comment: @Pavel, in my opinion, it's so much easier to use, everything is a widget and flutter controls every pixel in the page I made the app that took me three months to create in RN in 2 weeks with flutter

Comment: is it flexible enough? btw is your app online, curious to check it out.

Comment: @Pavel yes it's online it's a news/chat app